# Unable to run catkin_make install for sick_scan without a crash

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently attempting to use a tim561 along with a Raspberry Pi 3 b. On the Raspberry Pi I am using Lubuntu and ROS kinetic and attempting to install the [sick_scan](https://github.com/SICKAG/sick_scan) package. I am following the instructions for installing however whenever I run catkin_make install, or simply catkin_make it freezes the Pi such that I have to reboot it by unplugging it.

Knowing where it will freeze, I can stop catkin_make and I get the error message that I will paste below. I will also include the last two lines from the compilation if that helps.

Is it possible that the Pi is simply not powerful enough to run this install? Or do I need to install some other packages beforehand?

Thanks.

```
[ 63%] Building CXX object sick_scan/CMakeFiles/sick_scan_lib.dir/driver/src/sick_scan_common.cpp.o
[ 65%] Building CXX object sick_scan/CMakeFiles/sick_scan_lib.dir/driver/src/sick_scan_common_tcp.cpp.o
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_make", line 296, in 
sick_scan/CMakeFiles/sick_scan_lib.dir/build.make:350: recipe for target 'sick_scan/CMakeFiles/sick_scan_lib.dir/driver/src/sick_scan_common_tcp.cpp.o' failed
sys.exit(main())
make[2]: *** [sick_scan/CMakeFiles/sick_scan_lib.dir/driver/src/sick_scan_common_tcp.cpp.o] Interrupt
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/catkin_make", line 240, in main
run_command(cmd, make_path)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/builder.py", line 239, in run_command
sick_scan/CMakeFiles/sick_scan_lib.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'sick_scan/CMakeFiles/sick_scan_lib.dir/driver/src/sick_scan_common.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [sick_scan/CMakeFiles/sick_scan_lib.dir/driver/src/sick_scan_common.cpp.o] Interrupt
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4343: recipe for target 'sick_scan/CMakeFiles/sick_scan_lib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [sick_scan/CMakeFiles/sick_scan_lib.dir/all] Interrupt
proc.wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1392, in wait
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Interrupt
pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316941/unable-to-run-catkin_make-install-for-sick_scan-without-a-crash/) by [Pol](https://answers.ros.org/users/40249/pol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2019-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you are running out of resources on Raspberry Pi, compilation is quite memory/cpu intensive.

Have you tried running only one cmake thread? :

```
catkin_make -j1
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pol](https://answers.ros.org/users/40249/pol/) on 2019-02-27**:
Hi thanks for the reply. I have not tried that but that would make sense. I am however a bit unfamiliar with ROS, how many "j"'s are there? I noticed there is also j2, are there more? Would i also need to run catkin_make -j2? And for subsequent j's?
Thanks.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2019-02-27**:
The -j parameter is to inform CMake of how many threads to use for compilation. If you don't specify any -j then it will try to use all available CPUs. Your Rasberry Pi might have 2 cores, that is why you might have noticed the "j2".

**Comment by [Pol](https://answers.ros.org/users/40249/pol/) on 2019-03-01**:
That worked! Thanks!